# How get new owner and old owner of compressed nft form transaction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, transactions, cnft

I use solana network.
I sent compressed nft to other wallet.
How to get new owner and old owner of compressed nft from transaction? And how to detect that is burn or transfer transaction

Sent transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/5z4RQU5LQpAU2eoVjyqtGhEmqFgLHowzT4SxXgBjLcTZ1xp5V94rrwMr4RgBF1GMbxAy6ssdwwDHp3TcHwnp3E6y

Receive transaction
https://solscan.io/tx/2qVNc9F7i9fDECYoU9JikFoGf7KEtx9qcB2SHW32PgxfoDYDZXg9iaBxDBAvPeAJF3Q8Jh3hi8tbgYxqANFoRadS

Burn transaction
https://solscan.io/tx/55pNGwDim2E6BPyhDNcgaa8ecQD7R1kaDvfMU9hLaJiUQ2sNj5cFaG65ZPtQkL5hqBE2ox85PprByoxHwkejiS88

Buy cNFT
https://solscan.io/tx/4Ub2U5qnVmWP15HFU8ByFVQWVfs9WRqBfc2yP2z7GDzXifpbb1yGSTXPgGVxuEayz5yfQpT1BG3wRunYHoR55dCN

Comment: Could you share the tx link?

Comment: Links shared in question

Answer (score 3):

Compression uses the bubblegum program. Bubblegum uses anchor. You’ll need to decode the transaction using the bubblegum IDL, then pick the accounts matching the old leaf owner and new leaf owner.

If you view on explorer.Solana.com you can see these accounts.

Comment: Can u share some codes?

I tried to deserialize data using Bubblegum instruction using burnStruct.deserialize(...) and transferStruct.deserialize(..) but all returns result for transfer instruction without any errors and I cannot detect that was transfer or burn instruction for example.

Comment: Metaplex tends to generate idls with this thing called Solita. I don't like it. What I'd do is just use Anchor's Program.fetchIdl(program_id). Get the json. Find the instruction in the json. Find the index of the accounts you're looking for in that json, and then map it to the index of the accounts in the ix. Some similar logic here https://github.com/helium/helium-program-library/blob/ef2294b/packages/hotspot-data-sink/src/index.ts#L64

Comment: But how to detect that is burn instruction or transfer before?